# Killer 1535 802.11 2×2 Wi-Fi + BT 4.1 controller can't discover MS Mobile Mouse 3600

Tags: linux-mint, bluetooth, bluez

I saw number of posts here about Mobile Mouse 3600 but sadly none of them helped me to debug the issue.

I have Killer 1535 card on my Dell XPS 13. According to specs it's Bluetooth 4.1 device. Mobile Mouse 3600 is Bluetooth Low Energy device of version 4.0.

In theory these two devices should be able to communicate. Unfortunately they don't :(

I'm on Linux Mint 18 but I also tested it on Ubuntu MATE and Element OS. I have bluez 5.37 installed.

Here is what info I have abut my devices

hciconfig -a | grep HCI

```
HCI Version: 4.1 (0x7)  Revision: 0x0
```

lsusb | grep Ath

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0cf3:e301 Atheros Communications, Inc.
```

`sudo hcitool lescan` finds nothing.

After clean installation `dmesg | grep ath10` gives

```
[    3.464318] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.466450] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    3.702272] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:3a:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    3.702490] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin failed with error -2
[    3.702493] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not fetch firmware file 'ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0/firmware-5.bin': -2
[    5.910379] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 (0x05030000, 0x00340aff sub 1a56:1535) fw WLAN.RM.2.0-00180-QCARMSWPZ-1 fwapi 4 bdapi 2 htt-ver 3.26 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features wowlan,ignore-otp,no-4addr-pad
[    5.910382] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    5.990238] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0 wlp58s0: renamed from wlan0
```

My WiFi works. I can also pair Bluetooth keyboard. Since I don't really know how device drivers work in Linux I noticed line with error about `firmware-5.bin` in output of dmesg. So I took missing file from [here](https://github.com/kvalo/ath10k-firmware/tree/master/QCA6174/hw3.0/4.4). It turned out to be bad idea because it botched wifi/bluetooth completely. Here is what I had in log

```
[    3.519354] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.521259] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: pci irq msi-x interrupts 8 irq_mode 0 reset_mode 0
[    3.765880] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Direct firmware load for ath10k/cal-pci-0000:3a:00.0.bin failed with error -2
[    3.831220] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to fetch board data for ath10k/QCA6174/hw3.0 from bus=pci,bmi-chip-id=0,bmi-board-id=0/board-2.bin
[    5.887772] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[    5.887786] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: qca6174 hw3.2 (0x05030000, 0x00340aff bmi 0:0) fw WLAN.RM.4.4-00022-QCARMSWPZ-2 fwapi 5 bdapi 1 htt-ver 3.32 wmi-op 4 htt-op 3 cal otp max-sta 32 raw 0 hwcrypto 1 features wowlan,ignore-otp
[    5.887789] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: debug 0 debugfs 1 tracing 1 dfs 0 testmode 0
[    8.884160] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[    8.966789] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0 wlp58s0: renamed from wlan0
[   11.178547] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[   14.176459] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   20.176417] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   22.435758] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[   25.432569] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   31.432925] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   33.687090] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[   36.684683] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   42.685119] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   55.191367] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[   58.189447] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   64.189569] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   66.442090] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[   69.441647] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   75.441641] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   88.191952] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[   91.190185] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[   97.190065] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[   99.444307] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[  102.442543] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  108.442386] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  121.197006] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[  124.194704] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  130.194947] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  132.448783] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[  135.447000] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  141.447142] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  154.184800] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[  157.183488] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  163.183823] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  165.437951] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[  168.435897] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  174.436119] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  187.194437] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[  190.192217] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  196.192281] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
[  198.440901] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: Unknown eventid: 90118
[  201.440446] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: failed to enable dynamic BW: -11
[  207.440539] ath10k_pci 0000:3a:00.0: could not suspend target (-11)
```

How can I troubleshoot this ? What can I do to make this mouse become disoverable ?

Oh I also tried upgrading bluez to 5.43 but it didn't make any difference.

Comment: You need to file a bug report as this device is not supported in any Linux kernel at this time

Comment: @Jeremy31 Hmm but Bluetooth is technically supported. I'm able to connect external keyboard.

Comment: What kernel are you using? `uname -a`  The btusb source code can be changed to include your device with the other QCA Rome bluetooth ID's and with any luck it will load the firmware.  Most times these won't even sca without the firmware loading